# Worbench Password Management Sandbox - Malformed ID Error

Tags: workbench

I'm attempting to use Workbench's password management utility to set the passwords for some users in a sandbox, and I keep getting the error "MALFORMED_ID: bad id".  I've copied and pasted the username directly from the sandbox and verified it matched.  Does this feature not work in sandboxes?

Here is an example of an ID.  crm.firstname.lastname@orlandohealth.com.uat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workbench is expecting the 15- or 18-character ID of the user to set the password for. This Id starts with 005, as in 0053000000j8p0A or 0053000000j8p0AAAQ. You can find this by using a query:

```
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Username = 'crm.firstname.lastname@orlandohealth.com.uat'
```

or a REST resource like the following:

```
/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/user/Username/crm.firstname.lastname@orlandohealth.com.uat?fields=Id
```